# Fritzing unrouted connections with Autoroute

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, autorouter

Why does Fritzing's Autoroute leave unrouted connections?

Is there any way to tell it to route every connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not used Frtizing, but generally when autorouters leave unrouted connections it means they can't find a way to route them without breaking design rules.

Although they have come a long way, many folk still do some/most/all their routing manually, maybe using the autorouter first to get an idea of how easy it will be to route the board and optimise placement. They work better for some designs than others, usually layout/rule setup is a very important factor in how well they will perform.

A few suggestions:

- Alter design rule tolerances and try again (e.g. smaller trace clearance/width)
- Set router to try harder (usually a setting to specify how many times it will try before picking best option/giving up) or change routing topology.
- Add another layer to make routing easier (or add ground/power plane)
- Alter placement of components/board size to make more space, especially in congested areas.
- Give as much prior direction to autorouter (set up net areas, layers etc, if possible)
- Try another autorouter :-)
- Finish routing by hand

Comment: Thanks, that was a pretty complete answer. What I find weird is that Fritzing already places jumpers if it is unable to continue routing on the layer (I'm using a single-sided board), so why not place even more jumpers? Maybe this would be too complex for the autorouting algorithm? Anyways, really liked the answer, but haven't accepted it yet because maybe someone can provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Most autorouters are probably written with 2 and more layers in mind, so **may** be a bit flaky with one (I'm just guessing here though). Also maybe there is a setting to restrict the "willingness" of the router to use jumpers (or maybe a max limit number). I have seen similar in other Autorouters for e.g. vias. Hopefully someone who has actually used Fritzing can advise on the specifics. Until then I would play around with the settings (maybe on a simple test board to make understanding easier) and see what you can discover.

Comment: I don't know about the autorouter algorithm specifics, but I can tell you that Fritzing is a great software for beginners and DIYers (in my case, I'm both), and as such, the autorouter doesn't have many options. You can choose between a single-sided or a double-sided board, and you can specify the number of tries, but that's about it. I wanted a sigle-sided board because I've never etched a board before, so I'm ok with one side + jumpers. Anyway, I played a bit with Eagle (another software), but it was a no-go because I'm using a lot of non-standard components...

Comment: ... from Sparkfun, and Fritzing makes it easier to create custom parts (at least I thought so). So I went back to Fritzing and finished routing by hand, as you suggested. It was a real pain actually :( Thanks for your help!